# Can I use Snowflake as a relational database?

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

One of the SaaS tools we are working with is using a MySQL database as its main DB. Besides user-related data, it also receives some click-stream and various other information.

**About that DB:**

- Tables: 11
- Rows in the largest table: 7,000,000
- Total size: 17GB
- Daily writes: 50,000
- Daily reads: 1,000

Can Snowflake replace that MySQL database and what kind of performance boost we might expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid write oriented normalized relational database for reporting (even though it is snowflake kind of schema), due to following reasons. The database seems to be more write oriented and there could be lots of transactions happening.

1. The database is not designed for reporting. You need to still do lots of joins to arrive at result or you might need denormalization.
2. Readers block writers. When you are trying to read for reporting purposes, due to huge amount of data being read, there could be lock escalations happening on the table and it could put table level lock. Due to this lock, the writers will be blocked and it can cause the transactions to time out.
3. Doing huge reporting on the normalized database, could put additional load on the server and it can affect server performance.

I would suggest you to create replica database, using replication, ETL etc and use that for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As asked, the answer is "Yes".

**Big caveat**, Snowflake does not enforce PK or FK constraints! (Only null/not null.) As a result, your application will need to manage this. Because of this, I'd argue Snowflake is not a full RDBMS (relational database management system) because the definition implies relational management to be handled by the system.

I'd also agree with @venkataraman-r, Snowflake doesn't perform very well with OLTP behaviors directly. So you need to carefully manage that behavior.